# Hiding empty values in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SSRS report which has field with an empty values, based on yes/no parameter

When my parameter = No, this field appears as empty (no values)
When my parameter = Yes, this field has values

**Please, see the images below** -

"include Depreciation" Parameter = No,
"Depreciation" field is empty:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

"include Depreciation" Parameter = Yes,
"Depreciation" field is NOT empty

My goal is to hide the row when the parameter = No (and field has no values)

I was trying the following in SSRS:
In "**Design**" view in the table, clicked on an entire row responsible for "Depreciation", **Row Visibility**, **Visibility** - "**Show / Hide based on an expression**", entered the following expression:

```
=IIF(Isnothing(Fields!GLGroupLevel2Name.Value),false,true)
```

But it does nothing... An empty row (in case if parameter = No) still appears.

Here is my "Design" view 
(the row I modified with the conditional show/hide - is marked in grey):

Any suggestions or advice would be very helpful!
Thank you...

Comment: Your row visibility needs to be based on your parameter value? Not a dataset value.

Comment: Something like `=Not Parameters!ShowDepreciation.Value`

Comment: @DaleBurrell It could be based on the parameter value
If Parameter = 0 hide that row
  Parameter = 1 Show that row along w the others

I just tried =IIF(Parameters!Depreciation.Value=0,True,False)
Still no success

Comment: Test the the visibility is working by hardcoging the value to true and then to false. Assuming that is working, then the IIf must be failing, which could be down to a datatype mismatch. You could try `Parameters!Depreciation.Value=CInt(0)` assuming the parameter is an `int`.

Comment: @DaleBurrell
Even when I test my parameter Parameters!Depreciation.Value=True or
Parameters!Depreciation.Value=False - it still show that empty Depreciation row
It doesn't hide it as it supposed to

If this helps I can add what is it in withing T-SQL code - regarding that parameter
, CASE WHEN ((acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130')) AND (@Depreciation = 0)) THEN 0 ELSE trans.Amount END AS [Amount]
IIF((acct.[GLAccountCode]) IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130'), 1, 0) AS [DepreciationAcct]

Comment: There are 2 issues to solve, 1) Is the visibility setting being applied to the correct row/group etc & 2) Is the logic to determine visibility working. Unfortunately without having access to the report and the data source I can't really offer any further ideas. Sorry

Comment: Try this  `= IIf(Parameters!IncludeDepreciation.Value="No" And Fields!GLGroupLevel2Name.Value="Depreciation",True,False)` OR I think you have to add row visibility for GLGroupLevel1Name row i.e., `= IIf(Parameters!IncludeDepreciation.Value="No" And Fields!GLGroupLevel1Name.Value="Depreciation",True,False)`

Comment: @BhatiaAshish Thank you! Your answer helped!!!
I had to use your suggested expression on both GLGroupLevel1Name and GLGroupLevel0Name. (GLGroupLevel2Name was really hidden row, I provided the wrong reference)
Also, I had to include the expression in the Group section!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Try expression on Group Visibility***.

If your condition is fixed then Go to `Row Group Properties` and Apply your same expression in `Visibility` option based on your condition.

Use Expression as:

```
=iif((Fields!YourFieldName.Value <> "") ,false,true)
```

As shown in below image
[image]

This should work.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I had to add "Show or hide based on an expression" 
                 Visibility option into the Group visibility. 
                 I used the expression provided by the member above!